# How to find an arrow tip points given origin and end point of a line

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

Consider you have a line with start point (x1,y1) and end point (x2,y2).

In order to draw an arrow cap to the line (in objective-c), I need to find the points of the arrow (x3,y3,x4,y4) given the angle of the arrow (45 degrees), and the length of the arrow tips (h).

So given x1,y1,x2,y2,h,alpha whats x3,y3,x4,y4?

Added an image explaining the question.

If the answer can be in objective-c (using UIBezierpath and CGPoint) it will be much appreciated.

Thanks![image: arrow drawing]

Comment: Is this homework or something? Why wouldn't you make the arrow straight up rotate it using a context rotation?

Comment: @Metabble I think it's quite reasonable to do such a simple drawing from code and not to bother with loading an image...

Comment: Yes it is, depending on what you want to do, but I was just curious as to why they would bother. Maybe it's because I'm lazy. xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#import <math.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>

float phi = atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1); // substitute x1, x2, y1, y2 as needed
float tip1angle = phi - M_PI / 4; // -45°
float tip2angle = phi + M_PI / 4; // +45°

float x3 = x2 - h * cos(tip1angle); // substitute h here and for the following 3 places
float x4 = x2 - h * cos(tip2angle);
float y3 = y2 -  h * sin(tip1angle);
float y4 = y2 -  h * sin(tip2angle);

CGPoint arrowStartPoint = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
CGPoint arrowEndPoint = CGPointMake(x2, y2);
CGPoint arrowTip1EndPoint = CGPointMake(x3, y3);
CGPoint arrowTip2EndPoint = CGPointMake(x4, y4);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); // assuming an UIView subclass
[[UIColor redColor] set];
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, arrowStartPoint.x, arrowStartPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, arrowEndPoint.x, arrowEndPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, arrowTip1EndPoint.x, arrowTip1EndPoint.y);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, arrowEndPoint.x, arrowEndPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, arrowTip2EndPoint.x, arrowTip2EndPoint.y);
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks!!! Edited the plus to minus (becuase the arrow was upside down), but the calculations were correct! saved me time going back to Geomatry :)

Comment: @ozba your edit is incorrect IMHO. Atan2 returns a sign-correct angle.

Comment: mmm I've implemented it in my app, and the minus should be there or the arrow is flipped... Anyway great job! :)

Comment: Yes, you're right - I confused the starting and ending point of the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

This is my java implementation for my needs. **start** and **end** are Point objects.

```
    double lineAngle = Math.atan2(end.y-start.y, start.x-end.x);
    double ang1 = lineAngle-Math.PI/6;
    double ang2 = lineAngle+Math.PI/6;
    
    int tipLen = 30;
    Point tip1 = new Point(end.x+(int)(tipLen*Math.cos(ang1)), end.y-(int)(tipLen*Math.sin(ang1)));
    Point tip2 = new Point(end.x+(int)(tipLen*Math.cos(ang2)), end.y-(int)(tipLen*Math.sin(ang2)));
    
    g.drawLine(end.x,end.y,tip1.x,tip1.y);
    g.drawLine(end.x,end.y,tip2.x,tip2.y);
```

Calculate the angle of the tips and find their positions using angles.

Comment: FYI - the question is tagged Objective-C and iOS. An answer in Java isn't going to help much.

Comment: Thx, I didn't noticed that. I was looking smt for myself and interestingly I couldn't encounter anything close in a quick search, this question was the closest I found. Actually I shared it for people like me. The question owner asked it 11 years ago, he wouldn't need it anyway.